# NUnit 3: Timeout exceeded for first test

Tags: multithreading, nunit-3.0

I recently wrote a test fixture which constructed the code under test either in single-threaded or multi-threaded mode.

But one of the tests (A) consistently fails on the build agent, but only for the multi-threaded mode.
There is virtually no difference between the test that passed (B) and the 
test that failed (B).

So with two fixture attributes the two tests become four tests, and only 1 of 3 tests fails.

When running locally all four tests executes and passes in less than 20 milliseconds, so it's a really huge difference between 20 ms and exceeding a timeout of 5 seconds.

```
[TestFixture(MyCodeMode.SingleThreaded)]
[TestFixture(MyCodeMode.MultiThreaded)]
[Timeout(5000)]
public class MyCodeTests {
   private MyCodeMode _mode;
   public MyCodeTests(MyCodeMode mode) {
      _mode = mode;
   }
   private MyCode GetSystemUnderTest() {
      return new MyCode(_mode);
   }

   [Test]
   // this test fails when multi-threaded, passes in single-threaded
   public void MyTest_A_ThrowsInvalidOperationException() {
       Assert.Throws<InvalidOperationException>(() => GetSystemUnderTest().Execute(2));
   }

   [Test]
   // this test passes regardless of mode
   public void MyTest_B_ThrowsInvalidOperationException() {
      Assert.Throws<InvalidOperationException>(() => GetSystemUnderTest().Execute(3));
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`MyTest_A_ThrowsInvalidOperationException` is alphabetically sorted before `MyTest_B_ThrowsInvalidOperationException`.
And `MultiThreaded` is alphabetically sorted before `SingleThreaded`.

So the test exceeds the timeout because it's the first code to be executed and therefore takes all the impact of loading the required assemblies/types into the CLR. Subsequent tests re-uses the types already loaded into memory.

Adding a `OneTimeSetup` method with some code referencing the required code will force load the types before the individual tests are forked and measured.

```
[OneTimeSetup]
public void EnsureDependenciesHaveBeenLoadedIntoMemoryBeforeStartingTimeout() {
    new MyCode();
}
```

The build agent probably has very poor I/O performance (which for the sake of the tests is OK but adds a overhead penalty when loading additional dependencies).